# Ruby Code Comment Within Quotes

Tags: ruby, comments

I have a multi-line SQL command string in my Ruby script. I am adding some extra lines to the SQL command string, and want to supplement it with some in-line comments.

```
mysql.query("CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS #{table}(
    application varchar(255),
    eventType varchar(255),
    eventTs datetime,
    eventDayWeek int,
    newColumnHere int, #Hello, I would like to be a comment
    eventHourDay int,

    ....)")
```

How does one add code comments within a set of quotes?

Comment: what problem with code that you show us? are there some errors or something?

Comment: Apparently there is no problem. This does work after all because MySQL supports this commenting syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does support [comment syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) so your code should work as is.  However, I would prefer to use a "heredoc":

```
mysql.query <<END
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS #{table}(
    application varchar(255),
    eventType varchar(255),
    eventTs datetime,
    eventDayWeek int,
    newColumnHere int, #Hello, I would like to be a comment
    eventHourDay int,

    ....)
END
```

Comment: Does that "heredoc" work with the variable in the string "#{table}"?

Answer (score 2):

You could just break the string in two, or alternatively include an SQL comment.

For the first option:

```
"CREATE TABLE ...
newColumnHere int, " +
# comment in ruby here
"eventHourDay int, ...
```

Or the second option:

```
newColumnHere int,  -- SQL comments from double dash to end of line
eventHourDay int,
```